# c++ input array of char after input int

Tags: c++

I have an array of characters with variable size which is received from user input. From there I input the array with for loop based on the size but it seems like the variable holding the size is changing and I'm stuck in infinite loop.

```
char arr_1[] = {};
int array_size;

cout << "Array size: ";
cin >> array_size;
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
  cout << "Input: ";
  cin >> arr_1[i];
}
```

Comment: You never specify a size for your array.

Comment: Behaviour of your code is undefined.   The array must be sized appropriately BEFORE trying to access elements.    Accessing array elements does not magically resize the array in any way.  So if the array starts too small, it stays too small.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ technically, they've specified the size implicitly by using an initialization list. The size is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an array of characters with variable size
>
> ```
> char arr_1[] = {};
> ```

There is no such thing as "array with variable size" in C++. The size of an array never changes. Furthermore the size of non-dynamic arrays must be compile time constant. What you have declared there is an array of size zero. Non-dynamic arrays of zero size are ill-formed.

If the compiler for some reason fails to spot the bug (perhaps it supports zero length arrays as a language extension), then you end up accessing the array outside of bounds. The behaviour of accessing an array out of bounds is undefined. Infinite loop is one example of undefined behaviour.

There is however a standard container that will automatically reallocate a progressively larger array as you insert elements into it: `std::vector`.

Although, since you're dealing with characters, perhaps they're supposed to represent a character string. There is a special container for that purpose: `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Vector would be more appropriate to use than an array in this case. Even easier is to just work with a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numChars = 0;
    string word("");
    cout << "Num chars you want to input: ";
    cin >> numChars;

    for (int i = 0; i != numChars; ++i)
    {
        string input("");
        cout << "Enter a char: ";
        cin >> input;

        if (input.size() == 1)
            word += input;
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input- exiting";
            getchar();
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    cout << "Your word: " << word;
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```